# Code not working when PriceZoneID column is added

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a unique list of Departments from a database, as well as the Price Zone ID numbers for the Departments.

Does anyone know why this code works (getting a distinct list of Department names) but the subsequent code below doesn't (the only difference to it is that it has ps.PriceZoneID added - PriceZoneID is a column in the PriceZone table).

Code that works:

```
Select  
    distinct (es.DepartmentName)
FROM AggregatedSalesHistory as ASH 
JOIN v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID
JOIN PriceZone as ps on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID
```

Code that doesn't work.

```
Select
    ps.PriceZoneID,
    distinct (es.DepartmentName)
FROM AggregatedSalesHistory as ASH 
JOIN v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID
JOIN PriceZone as ps on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`Distinct` applies to all columns or expression & it is not function :

So, it would be :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ps.PriceZoneID, es.DepartmentName
FROM AggregatedSalesHistory as ASH JOIN 
     v_EnterpriseStructure as es 
     ON es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID JOIN 
     PriceZone as ps 
     ON es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID;
```

Or perhaps you need :

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES ps.PriceZoneID, es.DepartmentName
FROM AggregatedSalesHistory as ASH JOIN  
     v_EnterpriseStructure as es 
     ON es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID JOIN 
     PriceZone as ps 
     ON es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY es.DepartmentName ORDER BY ps.PriceZoneID);
```